# Performance: LEFT JOIN vs SUBQUERY

Tags: performance, postgresql, optimization, subquery, left-join

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3 and have the following tables (simplified to only show the relevant fields):

```
SITES:
id
name
...

DEVICES:
id
site_id
mac_address UNIQUE
...
```

Given the `mac_address` of a particular device, and I want to get the details of the associated `site`. I have the following two queries:

Using LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT s.* FROM sites s
LEFT JOIN devices d ON s.id = d.site_id
WHERE d.mac_address = '00:00:00:00:00:00';
```

Using SUBQUERY:

```
SELECT s.* FROM sites s
WHERE s.id IN (SELECT d.site_id FROM devices d WHERE d.mac_address = '00:00:00:00:00:00');
```

Which of the two queries would have the best performance over an infinitely growing database? I have always leaned towards the `LEFT JOIN` option, but would be interested to know how the performance of both rates on a large data set.

Comment: Take `EXPLAIN` and check it yourself.

Comment: Or even better: use `explain analyze`. Plus: if you have multiple rows in `devices` with the same mac_address, then those two statements are not doing the same thing.

Comment: I think they even generate different resultsets, so they are incomparable.

Comment: @Caramiriel I believe they return "identical" result sets.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name mac_address is unique in the devices table

Comment: @Caramiriel Both queries return exactly the same result set (s.*)

Comment: The `left join` query may return sites without device, whereas the `subquery` will only return sites that are actually mentioned in the device table.

Comment: @Caramiriel it cannot, since the rows from the `LEFT JOIN` are checked in `WHERE`

Comment: Ah true, well, why not simply inner join the query then?

Comment: @Caramiriel I have run both queries on multiple occasions, always receiving identical results :)

Comment: @Caramiriel that would be another question :-) Together with "After you tried `EXPLAIN` what have you discovered?" :-)

Comment: Guys, we're wasting each other's time - the solutions were provided in first two comments. How about we stop this chat and OP goes checking `EXPLAIN` ;-)

Comment: 'EXPLAIN ANALYZE' gives total runtime for both queries at an average of about 0.1 - 0.15ms. I only have a tiny data set to test with at the moment, which is why I was hoping someone might be able to shed light on possible performances over large data sets.

Comment: I'm sure `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` returns some more data than just a single number. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-explain.html --- please read the documentation, and if you have any **particular** question - ask.

Comment: "possible performances over large data sets" --- it might be either quick or fast.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It generally won't make any difference, because they should result in the same query plan. At least, an `EXISTS` subquery will; `IN` isn't as always as intelligently optimised.

For the subquery, rather than using `IN (...)` you should generally prefer `EXISTS (...)`.

```
SELECT s.*
FROM sites s
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM devices d
  WHERE d.mac_address = '00:00:00:00:00:00'
    AND d.site_id = s.id
);
```

Comment: As `mac_address` is unique, I don't think  `IN` vs. `EXISTS` will make a big difference.

Comment: I've never used `EXISTS` before, looks like it might be useful in this situation. From the documentation: "The subquery will generally only be executed far enough to determine whether at least one row is returned, not all the way to completion". Says to me that `EXISTS` will stop once `mac_address` is matched, where as `IN` will keep going. Could make a difference over hundreds of thousands of rows.